# NODEJS: Uncork() method on writable stream doesn't really flush the data

Tags: node.js, node.js-stream

I am writing quite simple application to transform data - read one file and write to another. Files are relatively large - 2 gb. However, what I found is that flush to the file system is not happening, on cork-uncork cycle, it only happens on end(), so the end() basically hangs the system until it's fully flashed.
I simplified the example so it just writes a line to the stream a lot of times.

```
var PREFIX = 'E:\\TEST\\';
var line = 'AA      11     999999999       20160101        123456  20160101                AAA     00      00   00      0       0       0       2       2       0       0       20160101        0       00';
var fileSystem = require('fs');


function writeStrings() {
var stringsCount = 0;
var stream = fileSystem.createWriteStream(PREFIX +'output.txt');
stream.once('drain', function () {
    console.log("drained");
});

stream.once('open', function (fileDescriptor) {
    var started = false;
    console.log('writing file ');
    stream.cork();
    for (i = 0; i < 2000000; i++) {
        stream.write(line + i);
        if (i % 10000 == 0) {
//                console.log('passed ',i);
        }
        if (i % 100000 == 0) {
            console.log('uncorcked ',i,stream._writableState.writing);
            stream.uncork();
            stream.cork();
        }

    }
    stream.end();
});

stream.once('finish', function () {
    console.log("done");
});

}

writeStrings();
```

going inside the node _stream_writable.js, I found that it flushes the buffer only on this condition:

```
    if (!state.writing &&
    !state.corked &&
    !state.finished &&
    !state.bufferProcessing &&
    state.buffer.length)
  clearBuffer(this, state);
```

and, as you can see from example, the writing flag doesn't set back after first uncork(), which prevents the uncork to flush.
Also, I don't see drain events evoking at all. Playing with highWaterMark doesn't help (actually doesn't seems to have effect on anything). Manually setting the writing to false (+ some other flags) indeed helped but this is surely wrong. 
Am I am misunderstanding the concept of this?

Comment: I was going to say that you need to call the first `stream.cork()` outside the `for` loop, but judging from your edit, that's the actual situation already?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Actually I now don't see the 'open' event in the node documentation, and I just wander where I take it. However, the question stays - how one would just write a bunch of lines inside the file, controlling the flushing? Because it does what it does, but just once.

Comment: Without looking too deeply into it, I think it has to do with writes, and therefore `uncork()`, being asynchronous. While the collected buffer is still being written, your code is continuing to run (hence the `writing` flag being true). Also, as far as I understand the docs, `drain` is emitted when it's safe to write, not when the internal buffer being used for `cork()` has been drained.

Comment: "collected buffer is still being written" - it starts to being written from the very beginning, however allows one flush.

Answer (score 2):

From the node.js documentation I found that number of uncork() should match the number of cork() call, I am not seeing matching stream.uncork() call for stream.cork(), which is called before the for loop. That might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at a guide on [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/backpressuring-in-streams/#rules-specific-to-writable-streams), you aren't supposed to call `stream.uncork()` twice in the same event loop. Here is an excerpt:

```
// Using .uncork() twice here makes two calls on the C++ layer, rendering the
// cork/uncork technique useless.
ws.cork();
ws.write('hello ');
ws.write('world ');
ws.uncork();

ws.cork();
ws.write('from ');
ws.write('Matteo');
ws.uncork();

// The correct way to write this is to utilize process.nextTick(), which fires
// on the next event loop.
ws.cork();
ws.write('hello ');
ws.write('world ');
process.nextTick(doUncork, ws);

ws.cork();
ws.write('from ');
ws.write('Matteo');
process.nextTick(doUncork, ws);

// as a global function
function doUncork(stream) {
  stream.uncork();
}
```

`.cork()` can be called as many times we want, we just need to be careful to call `.uncork()` the same amount of times to make it flow again.